# DataTable Rows to single Row Using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a single column with multiple rows in a DataTable, I want them In a single row, and dont want to loop through each row of data table,
Here is Sample Data Table

```
Results
-------
Clinet1
Clinet2
Clinet3
Clinet4
```

I want to get a string like
`Clinet1,Clinet2,Clinet3,Clinet4` but using LINQ without for loop.
I tried code below but its not working for me

```
string Details = myDataTable.Rows
                              .Cast<DataRow>()
                              .Where(x => x["Results"].ToString();
```

Comment: LINQ also uses loops internally. It will just make your code compact.

Comment: What is `UserName`? Are you want to filter based on something?

Comment: Sorry, there is no UserName filter now, I am doing it int query.

Comment: @Sangram: basically I dont want to itrate on records it takes too much time. Thats why I used DataTable instead to DataReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
string Details = myDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
.Where(x => x["Results"] == UserName)
.Select(i => i.ToString()).Aggregate((i, j) => i + "," + j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) for this.

```
string Details = String.join(",", myDataTable.Rows
                              .Cast<DataRow>()
                              .Where(x => x["Results"] == UserName).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) to return an `IEnumerable<T>` object, where the generic parameter `T` is `DataRow` and [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)  to join rows into a `string` like this;

```
    string rows = string
                    .Join(",", myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(x => x["Results"]));
```